# Remove duplicate all unique values in multiple array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data like this:

```
var data1 = ["RFCC","HCC","RFCC"];
var data2 = ["RFCC"];
```

I want to remove all duplicates from array above, the output should be like this:

```
var result = ["RFCC","HCC"];
```

If possible, how I could do the following task? Maybe someone could help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, sorry I have misspell my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first concatenate the arrays into a single array. Then use `filter()` by passing the current item, index and the array itself to check whether the *indexOf* of the current item is the current index or not.

Try the following way:

```js
var data1 = ["RFCC","HCC","RFCC"];
var data2 = ["RFCC"];
var res = data1.concat(data2);
res = res.filter((value, idx, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === idx;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @HamzahAznageel, you are most welcome:)